# Plot challenge: two bar charts next to next with one indicator line

Tags: plotting, charts

*Simple task:*
I would like to place two bar charts in a row and have an indicator horizontal line going above the two bar charts.

**What I did:**

```
bar1 = BarChart[{100, 75, 100}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartStyle -> {Blue, Black, Blue}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
   PlotLabel -> "bar1"];
bar2 = BarChart[{100, 38, 15, 38, 85}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartStyle -> {Blue, Black, White, Black, Blue}, Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> False, PlotLabel -> "bar2"];
indicator = 
  Plot[-65 + 100, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> ToString[65]];
```

To combine the plots, I tried:

```
Show[Row[bar1, bar2], indicator]
```

but the result:

[image]

HELP !
The colors need to be the same.

This is how it should look like in the end:
[image]

Comment: No, I misunderstood what you wanted. Actually, I don't know what you want. Is there some example figure out there that you could link to so that we can see what you want?

Comment: @march, I hope this helps.

Comment: `Row` requires the objects to be put in a list in the first argument, like in `Row[{obj1, obj2, ...}]`. You miss the curly braces in your code

Comment: Something like `Overlay[{GraphicsRow[{bar1, bar2}],indicator}]` but I am not sure where exactly you want that line to pass.

Comment: @march add answer?

Comment: @Feyre. Okay! I guess that seems reasonable. This is a pretty localized question, and I might say that `Epilog` is something that is "easily found in the documentation", but I posted a quick answer.

Comment: @march It's either answerable or close-able right?

Comment: @Feyre. Yep, and my initial thought was that this would be close-able, but I usually like to give quick answers in the comments if it *is close-able (because it helps the OP), and I *usually* wait for a couple of hours to see what other people do or if the question is updated before I vote to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Epilog` and `GraphicsRow`. Something like

```
GraphicsRow[{bar1, bar2},
  Spacings -> -20,
  Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.02], Line[{{0, -180}, {750, -180}}]}
 ]
```

and you can change the coordinates `{{0, -180}, {750, -180}}` of the `Line` by trial and error to get what you want (that's how I usually do it). The result is

[image]